# How do I change one button's action when another is clicked (SwiftUI)?

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, reference

In my app, I have a button that outputs a specific alert each time it's pressed. However, I want it so that when I click that button 10 times, the button's action and label will change, as I want to turn it into a restart button. How do I do so?

In other words, how do I refer to a button and modify its properties when it has no name to it?

'''swift

```
           Button(action: { alertIsVisible = true
                
            }) {
                Text(buttonText)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    
                
            }
            .alert(isPresented: $alertIsVisible, content: {
                let roundedValue = Int(sliderValue.rounded())
                let points = game.points(sliderValue: roundedValue)
                
                    return Alert(title: Text("Hello!"), message: Text("The slider's value is \(roundedValue).\n" + "You scored \(points) points this round"), dismissButton: .cancel(
                        
                                    {game.target = Int.random(in: 1...100)
                                        roundTracker += 1
                                        scoreTracker += points
                                    }
                        ))
                    
                })
```

'''

Comment: Can you show your code so far?

Comment: You can't refer to the button but you can use an `@State` or `@Published` the text for the `label` and add conditional to the action. Like `if count == 10` reset `else` increment count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, where the counter is stored as a `@State`. When the `counter` reaches `10`, it shows the 'restart' button instead.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter = 0

    var body: some View {
        if counter < 10 {
            Button("Press") {
                print("button pressed: \(counter)")
                counter += 1
            }
        } else {
            Button("Restart") {
                print("restart...")
                counter = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Okay, but how has it inferred that you are modifying the previous button in your example? Whenever I try to make a restart button after 10 rounds have been counted, it says "Result of 'Button<Label>' initializer is unused". How do I fix this?

Comment: @Krish The code in my answer works. What did you change? Seems like you may not be return the `Button` view, possibly there is another error?

Comment: My code is above. I tried adding an if statement beneath where it says "scoreTracker += points", yet it gave me the error that I told you. I am a beginner to Swift, so do you know how I can fix this? I wanted the code to execute after the cancel button of the alert is clicked, which is why I put it there.

Comment: I was actually able to work it out. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Krish If it's all working now, that's great news! Accepting the answer would be appreciated, and helps future users too with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can vary the `label` and the `action` of the `Button` according to the value of a `counter` variable (if it is well declared with the propertywrapper `@State`)

I used the ternary operator here:

```
struct CounterView: View {
    @State private var counter: Int = 0
    var exceeded: Bool  { counter >= 10 }
    func restart() {
        // do something
        counter = 0
    }
    func increment() {
        counter += 1
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(exceeded ? "Restart" : "Increment", action: exceeded ? restart : increment)
    }
}
```

## EDIT :

You can of course use a classic `if/else` rather than a ternary operator.
But it will **break** any **animations**, as this example shows (with an if / else these are two different buttons, and the animation is replaced by a classic transition, by default fade in/out) :

```
struct CounterView: View {
    @State private var counter: Int = 0
    var exceeded: Bool { counter >= 1 }
    func restart() {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2)) {
            counter = 0
        }
    }
    func increment() {
        counter += 1
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(exceeded ? "Restart" : "Increment", action: exceeded ? restart : increment)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .scaleEffect(exceeded ? 2 : 1)
            if exceeded {
                Button("Restart", action: restart)
                .scaleEffect(exceeded ? 2 : 1)
            } else {
                Button("Increment", action: increment)
                .scaleEffect(exceeded ? 2 : 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```